# We cannot evaluate A exactly, thus NEITHER(?) B(A), and have to rely on

Tags: neither-nor

Is the sentence

> We cannot evaluate A exactly, thus neither B(A), and have to rely on ...

okay? If not, what about

> We cannot evaluate A exactly, thus also not B(A), and have to rely on ...

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sentences are almost correct, the first and second phrases need to be **joined**, and a subsequent choice needs to be introduced

> We cannot evaluate A exactly, **and** thus neither B(A), **therefore we** have to rely on ...

You sentence is saying that since **A** cannot be solved **B**(**A**) (function **B** using **A**) also cannot be solved, so something else must be used